# How to add translation for a string

Tags: translation

My wordpress website is using non-english language (e.g chinese), and its backend already turned to chinese

but in wp-content\plugins\divi-builder\includes\no-results.php (i'm using divi builder, in side the file, the code

```
<!--If no results are found-->
<div class="entry">
    <h1>
        <?php esc_html_e( 'No Results Found', 'et_builder_plugin' ); ?>
    </h1>
    <p>
        <?php esc_html_e( 'The page you requested could not be found. Try refining your search, or use the navigation above to locate the post.', 'et_builder_plugin' ); ?>
    </p>
</div>
<!--End if no results are found-->
```

So, how can i translate the string inside esc_html_e?

Comment: Probably divi builder has no translations for chinese so this string won't be translated. You can translate it directly in your theme/plugin using po/mo files and add it to WordPress or using e.g. polylang plugin.

Comment: @motivast the divi has simplified chinese with file zh_CN.po and zh_CN.mo, do you know how to create a custom .po and .mo files?

Comment: I can give you some links:
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/translating-wordpress-plugins/
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

I do not know direct answer on your question but this maybe helps you.
You can use plugin Loco translate or you can do it manually like this.

```
_e( 'Search', 'name_tag_of_translation' );
```

Then go in wp-content/languages and there define what is you translation, in your case we talk about plugin, so you go:
wp-content/languages/plugins and find your plugin translation or make new file. Creating new file is important, read more on https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/localization/

My example of translation:

```
_e( 'Search', 'shopkeeperchild' );
```

Path where is translation: wp-content/languages/themes/
Files which are responsible for translation: 
shopkeeperchild-de_DE.mo /* Human readable */
shopkeeperchild-de_DE.po /* MAchine readable */
For translation I used PoEdit.